# Create chart using dynamic interactive ranges to select the series in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007, dynamic-data, charts

I would like to create a non-VBA based solution to the following question:

How do I create a multi-series chart that will allow a user to select from a dropdown to change the data being graphed?  I can do this already when the data series is contiguous; however, I'd like to be able to do it for non-contiguous data.  Is this possible?

My data look something like this:

```
  ID    Salary   Sal Min   Sal Mid   Sal Max   Division  Job Grade   Job Subgrade  Job
  XXX   10000    5000      15000     25000     North     13          1             Programmer
  XXX   12000    5000      15000     25000     North     13          1             Programmer
  XXX   14000    5000      15000     25000     South     13          1             Analyst
  XXX   11000    5000      15000     25000     South     13          1             Analyst
  XXX   20000    5000      15000     25000     North     14          1             Super Programmer
  XXX   25000    5000      15000     25000     North     14          1             Super Programmer
  XXX   22000    5000      15000     25000     North     14          1             Manager
  XXX   17000    5000      15000     25000     South     14          1             Manager
  XXX   19000    5000      15000     25000     South     14          1             Manager
```

I would like to display Salary, Sal Min, Sal Mid, and Sal Max using a line graph.  I would like the user to be able to select Job Grade, Division, and/or Job to determine what is charted.  Is this possible?  Would I somehow be able to do this if I used a pivottable or converted my data into a datatable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://processtrends.com/pg_interactive_chart_checkboxes.htm

Comment: Nothing happening when I click the link?